# Writing exit code of shell script into a file

Tags: xml, shell, exit-code

I have a shell script, which runs a tool.

What I want is, the exit code of this shell script should be written in a `.XML`file.

What I have done so far

```
# command1
# command2    
echo "<status>" > /home/buser/ABC/status.xml   // Writing into XML    
cp2foss -f ABC -q all /srv/foss/$archive_file2 --user foss --password foss; 
echo $? >>  /home/buser/ABC/status.xml   /// Wrting exit code into XML
echo "</status>" >> /home/buser/ABC/status.xml
```

Its working perfectly, but I dont think its a **good cosing practice.**

How can I write exit code in the XML file without such violation?

Comment: If you want a code review, consider using http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
# command1
# command2    
cp2foss -f ABC -q......
echo "<status>$?</status>" > path/to/status.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no *violations* in the above code, but you could write it this way:

```
cp2foss -f ABC -q all /srv/foss/$archive_file2 --user foss --password foss
printf '<status>%d</status>\n' "$?" > /home/buser/ABC/status.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer to write it like this as it's cleaner and easier to grok.

```
{ 
    echo "<status>" 
    cp2foss -f ABC -q all /srv/foss/$archive_file2 --user foss --password foss;
    echo $? 
    echo "</status>" 
} > /home/buser/ABC/status.xml   # Writing into XML
```